# Sort a set of coplanar 3d points in a desired order

Tags: c++, sorting, 3d

I have a set of three-dimensional points that all lie in the same plane.  The points are simply "x y z" entries in a text file.  **I would like to find a way to sort these points so that I could draw a simple polygon through all the points**.  I had several ideas:

**Idea 1:** Pick a point known to lie inside the polygon that is defined by the set of points and draw a ray to an arbitrary point in the set.  Then use an angular function of some sort to find the closest point *by angle* to the first one, then so on for all the rest.  The problem with this idea is that I don't know how to find a point that is guaranteed to be inside the region.  I wanted to use the centroid, but not all of these sets are going to be convex.  They could look like either of the following two images:

[image]

As you can see in the second image, the centroid may not lie inside the polygon, and actually if the turning point is too steep in the corner there the angular function that I had in mind might not work either.

**Idea 2:** This seems like one of the easier problems that could be solved according to something like the Traveling Salesman problem.  But I know there are lots of different particular solutions and approximations to solving TSPs and I am a bit rusty on where to begin.

**Idea 3:** Use a simple distance function that would start with an arbitrary point and find the the point that is closest to it, then find the point (not one already found) closest to *that* and so on.  This seems like the easiest one to do but I wonder if I am not forseeing any problems that arise.

I would appreciate any input as to the best way to solve this, and whether I am overlooking an even simpler method.  I am programming this in C++ so another good answer would include libraries or functions that can do things like find a 3d centroid, or solve a TSP, etc.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You could try the "ear clipping" algorithm to build correct, polygonal mesh.

Answer (score 0):

this is a tough problem If you add constraint that concave/convex gap is always bigger then max distance between any 2 neighboring points

[image: gaps]

then you should:

1. **for each point add 2 indexes**

   I would use for points storage something like this:

   ```cpp
   struct point
    {
    float x,y,z; // point coordinates
    int i0,i1; // index to 2 closest neighbors
    int tmp; // temp for computation purposes 
    };
   point pnt[n]; // n is number of points you got
   ```

   and clear them `i0,i1=-1;` There is a good idea to also add temp variable so you got space for flags during latter processing
2. **find closest neighbors**

   so for each point go through all points and remember 2 closest points to it. set their indexes to `i0,i1`. beware this is `O(n^2)` unless your points are spatially ordered. I see it like this:

   ```cpp
   for (i=0;i<n;i++) pnt[i].tmp=0;
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    i0=-1; l0=-1;
    i1=-1; l1=-1;
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
     if (i!=j)
      {
      x=pnt[i].x-pnt[j].x; x*=x;
      y=pnt[i].y-pnt[j].y; y*=y;
      z=pnt[i].z-pnt[j].z; z*=z;
      l=x+y+z;
           if ((l0<0.0)||(l<=l0)) { i1=i0; l1=l0; i0=j; l0=l; }
      else if ((l1<0.0)||(l<=l1)) {               i1=j; l1=l; }
      }
    pnt[i].i0=i0; pnt[i0].tmp++;
    pnt[i].i1=i1; pnt[i1].tmp++;
    }
   ```

   Now the `i0,i1>=0` and `temp==2` for all valid points. All of the points should be valid if not then the constraint was not met or you got grouped the points wrongly (on one side of point is high density on the other is low so both neighbors are just on one side)
3. **form the polyline**

   so start on first valid point you found and use it as first point of your polyline/polygon. Then look use its `i0` and so on until you hit the starting point or invalid `i0`. Something like this (assuming all points are valid):

   ```cpp
    for (i0=0,i=0;;i++)
     {
     if (i<0) break; // not valid point
     // here add pnt[i] to polyline
     i=pnt[i].i0;
     if (i==i0) break; // end of polyline/polygon
     }
   ```

In case you got also invalid points then you should recursively do this on the remaining points (not including already valid points) and also use some max limits for distances so you do not merge point that do not belong to each other. After this you should got few polylines so join them if their endpoints are close ...

To improve **#2** you can add condition that neighboring points are not in similar direction but that can affect sharp edges.

If nothing helps you can use convex hull and then remove all vertices that does not correspond to your sample points (concave parts) and recursively do the missing parts. At last join the polylines to single polygon